# How do i make my code case insensitive using the match case function

Tags: string, case-insensitive

I've written a code that prompt the user for input and output the data that matches to it. I'm using the match case function how do I make case insensitive. I've tried .lower() in input but the code won't work unless i remove and its only matching the data if the input is exactly the same as the one ive typed in ?

I've tried using the str.lower() but it doesent out the data unless i remove it

```
fruits = input("Enter fruit: ")

match fruits:
    case "Apple":
        print("Calories: ", 130)

    case "Avocado":
        print("Calories: ", 50)

    case "Banana":
        print("Calories: ",110)

    case "Cantaloupe":
        print("Calories :", 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, notice the lowercase for Cases,

```
fruits = input("Enter fruit: ")

match fruits.lower():
  case "apple":
    print("Calories: ", 130)

  case "avocado":
    print("Calories: ", 50)

  case "banana":
    print("Calories: ",110)

  case "cantaloupe":
    print("Calories :", 50)
```